# The voltage across all points in this circuit seems to drop once an inductor is added

Tags: coil, tesla-coil

I'm at the end of my wits after spending the last few hours trying to work this out, so bear with me. I have the following circuit:

[image]

My resistor is a 47k resister, my D1 and D2 are UF4007 diodes. My transistor is also a TIP31C, while my L1 has about 8 turns and my L2 has about 400 turns, with a 9V battery. However, what I am finding is that this circuit simply does not work -- most of the time, when I measure voltage across L1 and L2, I get a value that makes sense -- L1 is about ~0.02V and L2 is maybe ~0.6V, meaning that I am multiplying by the ratio between the two, so I know that something's happening.

I have, however, gotten it to work once, briefly, for about a half second, where it lit my 13W CFL lightbulb.

But now I'm finding a much bigger problem.
My voltage has dropped. Everywhere.

I'm using the 9V battery -- the voltmeter reads 8.3v across the battery, but ~0.6-0.7V between ground and any position on the circuit, including, but not limited to the topload, either end of L1, either end of the resistor, and directly between the positive wire and ground.

Yet I can also return the voltage to normal -- if I remove L1, then voltage across the circuit returns to normal.... But then the circuit won't work anymore because... Well it needs L1 to work.

So now I'm stuck -- L1 seems to drop my voltage down from ~8.4V to ~0.6V, everywhere.

I'm stuck, and google isn't helping.

Other information:

L1 is wound clockwise, L2 is counterclockwise
Topload is a styrofoam ball with aluminum foil around it
L2 wire is 30AWG and L1 wire is 24
L2 is wrapped around a 1/2" PVC pipe and L1 is wrapped right around L2.

So yep, Google isn't giving me anything on this. Any help would be appreciated, as I've been working on this circuit for the last week, and I'm hitting a dead end here.

Thank you.

Comment: What is this circuit supposed to do? You're connecting it to a styrofoam ball...?

Comment: Have you checked the transistor is still OK? Looks like the circuit will short thru C-E once L1 gets up to full current. Do you need a current- limiting resistor in there somewhere?

Comment: This is the Slayer Exciter cicruit. From what I understand, this circuit is supposed to use L1 to induce a voltage of sorts into L2, and then L2 is supposed to be connecetd to a topload (In my case, an alumnum foil wrapped styrofoam ball), exciting a flourescent lightbulb when it is placed near it. Here's the guide I'm following. http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Build-a-Slayer-Exciter/ The transistor's okay, I've checked. I'm not sure about the current limiting resistor because nobody else seems to use one, and theirs all work.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the polarity of L1. Your description is consistent with it not oscillating, the voltages dropping everywhere, and this would be my first thing to check.

Comment: How does one go about swapping the polarity of a coil? Would just switching the leads work? Or is it that we have to re-wind the coil completely?

Comment: Switching the leads should work fine.